# VS Code data science variables explorer and viewer options

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When working interactively, I often use the `from x import *` pattern, but when I do this with non-user defined libraries, everything imported from that library shows up in the variables explorer. (Eg when I do `from numpy import *` 100+ variables are added that I don't really care about)

Ideally I would like for only variables locally defined, or objects imported from user defined libraries to show up in the variable explorer. I've looked through the settings and think that this option might help me accomplish my goal but I can't find any documentation on them so I'm not sure which modifications to make:

```
"python.dataScience.variableExplorerExclude": "module;function;builtin_function_or_method"
```

It would be cool if I could add `";thirdparty_function_or_method_or_class"` where that would just be anything defined in the site packages of my virtual environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be really hard from the developer's perspective. because python is a language that using lexical scoping as the scoping rule.
Also, it's good practice to does not use `from numpy import *` like at the top
cuz it'll add all the functional and non-function variables to current *namesapce*. So, this increases the memory usage of your file, and the process you are creating is a time-critical one, then high memory usage kills the performance.

However, Pycharm variable Explora suitable for your case up to some extent, that because there shows your all the local variable with showing all the global scope variables and it's very nice and detailed.